# The website is addressing 2 categories (employers and candidates), Which one should we be addressing more?

Tags: user-research, information-architecture, content-strategy

I am working on a website that addresses both employers and candidates, and the user should choose whether he is an employer or a candidate from the homepage.
But i am lost here, If i want to add the benefits or how it works on the homepage? should i put it for the employers or for the candidates? or for neither and add them inside when the user chooses his category?

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing very much about what your website does, I would suggest having a homepage that looks something like this:

[image: Homepage wireframe]

At the top of your screen, let the users know a little about who your company is and what they do, then in order to provide more specific information towards Employers or Candidates, create two sections and list a few benefits for each party. Within those sections you can provide links so the user can continue on the path that applies to them.

Answer (score 0):

Since the nature of the site is kind of vague, i am presuming that it is for an organization.

If by candidates, you mean general public who can visit the site without logging in then it would be helpful for them to read the *potential benefits which the organization provides* . It could communicate a clear idea to the visitors about the organization.

Once an employee logs in , you can very well add the employee perks to the list.

Or you can show them **both** which by itself will be a motivation to the candidates to become potential employees.